# Docker will not expose ports when using internal network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

When I configure an [internal network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#internal) in my `docker-compose` file, exposing ports via the [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) option will not work anymore.

Let's consider the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
    networks: 
      - internal
networks: 
  internal:
    internal: true
```

When I run it with `internal: false`, everything is fine, and the port 5000 will be mapped to the host. When I run it with the `internal: true` option, the is no port mapping anymore:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
de6412f692e7        registry:2                              "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                           registry_registry_1
```

However, I can still reach the port via the internal network from the host:

```
$ docker-compose exec registry ip addr
[...]
    inet 172.23.0.2/16 [...]
$ curl -v 172.23.0.2:5000
[...]
> GET / HTTP/1.1
[...]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]
```

So there should be no technical reason why `docker-proxy` cannot proxy the container port to the host or is there anything I missed?

Comment: I read the `internal` documentation as meaning that containers on that network can’t communicate with the host or the outside, at all, in either direction.  What effect do you want from `internal: true`?

Comment: It is true that the container cannot communicate with the outside but as the docker host gets an IP in the internal network it can still communicate with the host. The ``curl`` command shows it.

Comment: @sven.to did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @vab2048 Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution, yet. :-/